Build Hyperlink from Cells in Another Workbook?
I have two workbooks:
Workbook1
Workbook2
In workbook 2, I have text in cell A1. The text could be a website url, or the filepath of a file in windows, or whatever.
In workbook1, I want to build a Hyperlink formula which gets its "link_location" from cell A1 in Workbook2.
I build the following formula in, say, cell C3 of Workbook1:
=HYPERLINK('C:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\[Workbook2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1,"Test")
The hyperlink works correctly, and opens the website/file/whatever listed in cell A1 of Workbook2... but only if Workbook2 is open. As soon as I close Workbook2, clicking the link in Workbook1 does nothing. It's still there, and does not give any error (even after F2->Enter). It just... does nothing when clicked.
Now, if I go to Workbook1, and in cell, say, E5, I enter the following formula:
='C:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\[Workbook2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1
This populates cell E5 in Workbook1 with the text from cell A1 of Workbook2. If I then replace the formula in cell C3 of Workbook1 with the following formula:
=HYPERLINK(E5,"Test")
Then the link works, and continues to work even when Workbook2 is closed.
What gives? Is there a way to make this work without the "middle man" formula?

External links to Closed workbooks are considered a potential Security Concern; hence why Microsoft enacts certain restrictions around them.  Especially in situations like this, where you can't see the value of the Hyperlink until after you've clicked on it…
